# Creating a data stream with Flask - Python

Tags: python, rest, http, flask, stream

I'm developing a server that fetches log files from a server with `Flask`.
Here's a snippet of the method that fetches the logs:

```
@app.route('/logs', methods=['POST'])
def logs():
    if request.method == 'POST':
      if request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/octet-stream':
            return not_implemented()

        if request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/gzip':
            # @TODO: Implement me: I must return a gzip file
            return not_implemented()
```

What I want is to create a stream, so when I do a `POST` request to `/logs` with param `filename=foo.txt`, I want to return a stream, so I can read the file on my client side. So far, I have attempted to write the following method:

```
def get_stream(filename):
    """Return the file as a stream of binaries

    :return file: A file pointer for the binary file
    """
    chunk_size = 4096
    try:
        if os.path.exists(filename):
            with open(filename, "bw") as f:
                while True:
                    chunk = f.read(chunk_size)
                    #@TODO: Add the remaining of the implementation
    except Exception, ex:
        log.error(ex)
        return None
```

I don't understand how can I use `yield` to return an iterator to the `get_stream()` method. I know I have to return something like:

```
return Response(get_stream("foo.txt"), mimetype="application/octet-stream")
```

Could someone help me with that?